# Flutter - Cannot set Notification large icon

Tags: flutter, firebase-notifications, flutter-notification

I'm using:   flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+3

I'm showing notification like this, its all working. The custom icon is also working. BUt I'm trying to set a large icon, and its just not showing. Here is a screen shot of the notification without any large icon:

UPDATE - It shows when I lock the phone, and the notification is showing on the lock screen. But, when it pops up on the screen, it doesnt show. ALso, when I swipe down and see all the notifications in a list, it doesn't show. Only on the lock screen. Why would this be?

[image: No icon]

Here is my code:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    notificationPermission();
    initMessaging();

    subscribeToTopic('test');

    createChannel();


    super.initState();
  }

  // users unique token
  void getToken() async {
    print(await messaging.getToken());
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    getToken();
    // showNotification();

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('AppBar Demo')),



      ),
    );
  }




  void notificationPermission() async {

    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
  }

  void initMessaging(){

    // for notifications:
    var androidInit = AndroidInitializationSettings('my_icon');   // make sure this is in drawable folder in android

    var iosInit = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSetting = InitializationSettings(android: androidInit, iOS: iosInit);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetting);

    // Set up listener

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');

      showNotification(message.data['title'], message.data['body']);

      if (message.notification != null) {
        print('Message also contained a notification title: ${message.notification.title}');
        print('Message also contained a notification body: ${message.notification.body}');
      }
    });

  }

  void showNotification(String title, String body) async {

    var androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        '91512',
        'channelName',
        'channelDescription',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        visibility: NotificationVisibility.public,
        ticker: 'ticker',
        largeIcon: const DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('my_icon'),

    );

    var iosDetails = IOSNotificationDetails();

    var generalNotificationDetails = NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iosDetails);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, title, body, generalNotificationDetails, payload: 'Notification');


  }

  void subscribeToTopic(String topicName) async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(topicName).whenComplete(() =>
    {
      print('Sucessfully subscribed to topic: $topicName')
    });
  }

  void unsubscribeToTopic(String topicName) async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic(topicName);
  }

  Future<void> createChannel() async {

    // create channel:
    var androidNotificationChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      '91512',  // channel ID
      'Your Channel name',    // channel name
      'Your Channel description', //channel description
      importance: Importance.high,

    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(androidNotificationChannel);

  }


}
```

Answer (score 14):

I think you are looking for AndroidNotificationDetails, give you an example:

```
AndroidNotificationDetails(
        channel.id,
        channel.name,
        channel.description,
        channelShowBadge: true,
        icon: '@mipmap/ic_icon',
        largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('@mipmap/ic_largeIcon'),
),
```

As you can see in the notification anatomy, it's not recommended to set the app icon in largeIcon property:

[image: Android Notification anatomy]

The correct way to use largeIcon is using the image property in notification payload when you are sending the notification:

```
const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: 'title',
          body: 'description',
          image: 'link-to-your-large-image',
          sound : "default",
          badge: "1"
        },
      };
```

[Android Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications)

Comment: what about ios? I want to show largeicon in ios notification.